# How to Open new link in Safari with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a workflow to click through a webpage to complete an action at the end. I currently have it working, however I'd like it to open the first "button" that it clicks in a new tab.

I've already tried telling in to open a new tab, but I don't know how to make it open the first button it has to click in a new tab.

```
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickClassName

clickClassName("settings", 0)
delay 3
clickClassName("Button Button--link Button--link--has-divider Button--course-settings validator_link", 0)
delay 2
clickClassName("Button Button--primary", 0)
```

I expect it to open the `clickClassName("settings", 0)` page in a new tab

Comment: You'll need to know the URL of the page in question. AppleScript will open a new tab using `open location` targeted at Safari, but needs a URL; JavaScript will open a new tab or window with `window.open()` but also needs a URL.

Comment: @CJK So I can't have it open a page in a new tab if I don't know the URL before-hand? The reason I ask is because my job is extremely repetitive but every course that I go into has a different identifier in the URL.